# Sintaxe do retorno em objeto em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sintaxe

Utilizando o console do Google Chrome utilizei o seguinte código (válido):

```
function foo()
{
    return {
        prop: "some value"
    };
}
```

quando é trocada o estilo de sintaxe não é mais válido (`{` jogado para próxima linha):

```
function foo()
{
    return 
    {
        prop: "some value"
    };
}
```

[image: teste no Chrome]

Isso é uma regra de sintaxe do JavaScript ou um *bug* de implementação dos navegadores? Testei isto no Internet Explorer também (mesmo comportamento).

Comment: Certeza de que não existe mais nada no código que possa estar lhe dando um falso-positivo? Porque [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/hfHFk/), no Chrome mais recente, funcionou, tranquilamente, isto é, o alert() mostou **value**.

Comment: certeza, estou testando apenas o básico, seu código é a primeira versão que postei, olha só: http://jsfiddle.net/hfHFk/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A syntaxe é:

> return [ expression ];

E diz em relação à "expression":

> A *expression* de retorno. Se omitida, *undefined* será o retorno.

<sub>[Fonte MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)</sub>

Isso implica que a expressão, variável, objeto, etc estejam na mesma linha do código. Se mudar de linha o intérprete vai pensar que tem um `return` isolado e faz `return` de `undefined`.

Comment: `If omitted, undefined is returned instead.` Obrigado @Sergio, acho que tirei minha dúvida

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @Sergio, é necessário colocar na mesma linha pois o ponto-e-vírgula, em Javascript, é opcional.

Quando você faz:

```
return 
{
    prop: "some value"
};
```

O interpretador entende como:

```
return;
{
    prop: "some value"
};
```

Comment: Obrigado @Beterraba, estava pensando nisso ontem... é um dos princípios que tinha esquecido hehe